Trying to set fixed IP in a Unifi environment (UDMPRO) with Powershell fails with 403, Forbidden
I am trying to set a fixed IP  in a Unifi environment (UDMPRO) with Powershell. I can connect, and list connected clients, but when I try the PUT command I get
Invoke-Restmethod : {"error":{"code":403,"message":"Forbidden"}}
This is my code:
$Mac =  "94:9f:3e:b1:27:3c"

[String]$Controller = "https://192.168.1.1"

$cred = Get-Credential
$credentials = "`{`"username`":`"$($cred.username)`",`"password`":`"$($cred.GetNetworkCredential().password)`"`}"

# Ignore self-signed certificates 
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::ServerCertificateValidationCallback = { $true }

$LoginURI="$Controller/api/auth/login"
$Session = New-Object Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WebRequestSession
$results = Invoke-Restmethod -Uri $LoginURI -method post -body $credentials -ContentType "application/json; charset=utf-8"  -WebSession $Session -TimeoutSec 600

$name = 'default'
$URI = "$controller/proxy/network/api/s/$name/stat/sta"
$request = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $URI -WebSession $Session
$Client = $request.data | where { $_.mac -eq  $Mac } 
$ClientId = $Client._id
$Ip = $Client.last_ip
 
$FixedIP = @{
    "use_fixedip" = $True
    "fixed_ip" = $Ip
    }
$FixedIPJson = $FixedIP | ConvertTo-Json

$URI = "$controller/proxy/network/api/s/$name/rest/user/$ClientId"
$header = @{"accept" = "application/json","text/plain"}
$Fixedresult = Invoke-Restmethod -Uri $URI -method PUT -Headers $header -Body $FixedIPJson  -ContentType "application/json; charset=utf-8"  -WebSession $Session
$Fixedresult

Does anyone have an idea what I am doing wrong?

You do not have the permission to the route.  The route is the end path of the URI

I have found the problem: a X-Csrf-Token header field is needed:
$Token = ((((($Session).Cookies).GetType().InvokeMember('m_domainTable', [Reflection.BindingFlags]::NonPublic -bor [Reflection.BindingFlags]::GetField -bor [Reflection.BindingFlags]::Instance, $null, (($Session).Cookies), @())).Values).Values).value
$csrfToken = (ConvertFrom-Json -InputObject (Base64UrlDecode -base64Url ($Token -split '\.')[1])).csrfToken

Then I can use $csrfToken in the headers:
$headers = @{
    "accept" = "application/json";
    "content-type"= "application/json";
    "X-Csrf-Token" = $csrfToken
}


Thanks for sharing a solution. I've consolidate your two answers, so I suggest deleting the older one. It's generally preferable to update an existing answer rather than to post a new one.
